# .replace only if comma followed by text with no blank space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to achieve the following...

Having this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ,adipiscing elit
```

I need to create a replace function that replaces the commas followed with a char only if there's no blank space between them, while keeping the char and other commas that have spaces.

For the example above, the output should be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

I've tried:

```
var test = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ,adipiscing elit"
test = test.replace(/\,b/g, '');
```

but it also replaces the char, so it returns:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit
```

Comment: Show, if input="An , input", then is output="An , input" ? So it remains the same?

Comment: You have a typo: /\,b/ should be: /,\b/ then it works

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to replace only those commas that are followed with a word character (no space) - you should use a lookahead to check if the next character after the comma is a word character. `\b` does not work as it signifies word boundary, which also includes   (space).

```js
let test = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ,adipiscing elit';
console.log(test.replace(/,(?=\w)/g, ''));
```

Edit: Obligatory [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VkC95g/1)